# Compress and decompress a string from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, file, compression

I need to compress some text, I'm wondering if my program could be made more efficient. The only things I could think of would be the 'import re' and turning the filename input and read part as a function.

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval


################## Compression #####################
def comp():
    while True:
        try:
            fileName=input('Please input text file name in current directory: ')+'.txt'
            a=open(fileName)
            break
        except:
            print('No Such text file in current directory name: '+fileName)

    content = a.read()
    a.close()

    p = re.compile(r'[\w]+|[\W]')
    split = p.findall(content)

    b = []
    wordList = []

    for word in split:
        try:
            r = wordList.index(word) + 1
        except ValueError:
            wordList.append(word)
            r = len(wordList)
        b.append(r)

    f=open('compressed.txt', 'w')
    f=open('compressed.txt', 'r+')
    f.write(str(wordList)+'\n'+str(b))
    f.close()

####################################################

################## De-Compression ##################

def decomp():
    while True:
        try:
            fileName=input('Please input text file name in current directory: ')+'.txt'
            a=open(fileName)
            break
        except:
            print('No Such text file in current directory name: '+fileName)

    words = literal_eval(a.readline().rstrip('\n'))
    pos = literal_eval(a.readline())

    temp = []

    for index in pos:
        temp.append(words[index-1])
    sentence = ''.join(temp)
    print(sentence)
####################################################
```

Comment: Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*, as you have an answer that directly addressed the code you removed.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, not much to do, I only defined the file read as a function, used the `with` context manager to read and write files instead of opening and closing, some PEP8 enhancements and `string.format()` instead of concatenation.

```
import re
import os
from ast import literal_eval


def get_filename():
    while True:
        filename = input('Please input text file name in current directory: \n')
        filename = filename if filename.endswith('.txt') else '{}.txt'.format(filename)
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            return filename
        else:
            print('No Such text file in current directory: {}'.format(filename))


def comp():
    with open(get_filename(), 'rb') as file_in:
        p = re.compile(r'[\w]+|[\W]')
        split = p.findall(file_in.read())

    word_list, b = []
    for word in split:
        try:
            r = word_list.index(word) + 1
        except ValueError:
            word_list.append(word)
            r = len(word_list)
        b.append(r)

        with open('compressed.txt', 'r+') as file_out:
            file_out.write('{}\n{}'.format(str(word_list), str(b)))


def decomp():
    with open(get_filename(), 'rb') as file_in:
        words = literal_eval(file_in.readline().rstrip('\n'))
        pos = literal_eval(file_in.readline())

    temp = []

    for index in pos:
        temp.append(words[index-1])
    print(''.join(temp))
```

I might help some more, but need some more context on what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe working on multiple files, taking filenames as arguments or some more improvements.

**EDIT:**

After reviewing the assignment the previous solution won't take care of punctuation, this will:

```
import string
import os


def get_filename():
    """Function to get the file name from user input"""
    # Infinite loop to ask the user for a file name that must be valid in order to break the loop.
    while True:
        # Ask the user for a file name.
        filename = input('Please input text file name in current directory: \n')
        # Append .txt extension if not provided.
        filename = filename if filename.endswith('.txt') else '{}.txt'.format(filename)
        # Test if the file exist and return it, print an error and continue loop if not.
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            return filename
        else:
            print('No Such text file in current directory: {}'.format(filename))


def comp():
    filename = get_filename()
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_in:
        full_text = file_in.read()

    # Making a translation table to get rid of punctuation and keep only letters.
    table = str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' ' * len(string.punctuation))
    only_words = full_text.translate(table)
    # Create a sorted list of unique elements.
    word_list = sorted(set(only_words.split()))
    # Replace every word of the original text by it's index in the word list.
    for index, word in enumerate(word_list):
        full_text = full_text.replace(word, '{{{}}}'.format(index))  # Double brackets are ignored by .format()

    # Create a separate file with the same name but _COMP_, to dump the compressed text.
    with open('_COMP_{}'.format(filename), 'w') as file_out:
        file_out.write('{}\n***{}***'.format(full_text, '|'.join(word_list)))  # The word list reference is appended.


def decomp():
    with open(get_filename(), 'r') as file_in:
        # Read each line to a list element.
        full_text = file_in.readlines()
        # Remove the last line of the text and convert it to a sorted list of the reference words.
        reference = sorted(full_text.pop(-1).strip('*').split('|'))
    # Print the full text replacing the indexes by the corresponding word in the list.
    print(''.join(full_text).format(*reference))
```

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself wrong, the second script I posted keeps punctuation in place while compressing everything else.